# Django extending User Model which strategy can use (Beginner ;) )

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration

I want to add additional fields of information in my registration page like (address, phone number ... etc) and ask the user to browse documents on his computer in order to transmit them during registration.
I saw that there are several ways to implement this [How to Extend user model](http://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

I have seen that there are several ways to customize the default User model, but I do not know which one to choose and how to set up the uploading of documents

THANX FOR HELPIN !

Comment: The best way to do this is by creating a profile model that contains all additional fields and a one-to-one relationship with the Django User model.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, what about adding an ""upload documents"" part during the registration process ?? i have no idea !

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `Profile` class which extends the `User` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks i did it usig OneToOneField .

Comment: Still looking for how to add an "upload process" during the registration 
for expl: i need him to upload like five or six 'PDF' files or (jpg,png...)
each upload line will be represented in a field ! :/

Comment: @VITALYSWEB I think this is another question.